# Can not get to login screen, background starts with terminal prompt only

Tags: boot, login

My uncle has Ubuntu on his work PC. I came in to work today, and he had lost his Unity side bar. I told him start with just rebooting it. He rebooted it... and now it does not even get to the login screen.

It gets to the background with the word Ubuntu, and the 6 or 7 dots, does it's little
loading dot thing and then stops, a black terminal then opens on the top left with the background still in place. Personally, I think he screwed it up himself. He always swears he didn't touch anything, but I know better...

Either way, I can't get him back into the desktop to even see if the sidebar is back. He's always screwing around pressing the wrong buttons on the login screen, hitting admin things and such...

Any ideas?

Comment: try running the command `unity --reset` when you get to that terminal.

Answer (score 0):

He can try to reinstall unity as part of the ubuntu desktop, with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Then restart and wait...

(If he is not logged in to his user account, he'll need to do that first.)

Comment: Thank you, actually managed to get it back. I first uninstalled and reinstalled GRUB. Somehow the 2nd reboot I got in to the login. THEN it started going into the desktop, and kicking back out to login screen. But no terminal.

Found some commands somewhere through google. Something to do with lightdm. Did that, rebooted, and I was back in. Ran updates, rebooted again, and it auto-logged right in. 

Thanks though!

Comment: This is what I used:

sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup

sudo service lightdm restart